# How to split a BodyText (Sentences) into specific number of words and put them in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I want to split a BodyText (some Sentences = over 3000 words) into a specific number of words (for example 500 words), and put them in an array.
Means that every block of that array should have 500 words and we will have the rest in the last block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the general character to split words on is a space, try this. It splits the words on a whitespace, then it puts them in a list by groups of 500:

```
string[] sentences = bodyText.Split(' ');

List<string[]> parts = new List<string[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < sentences.Length; i += 500)
{
    parts.Add(sentences.Skip(i).Take(500).ToArray());
}
```

If you want the end result in an array, you could use `ToArray()`:

```
string[][] endArray = parts.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

I did it with a richtextbox and a list.

```
List<string> words=new List<string>();
string[] splittedWords = rich.Text.Split(' ');
int counter = 0;
StringBuilder tempWordHolder=new StringBuilder();

foreach (string word in splittedWords)
{
    tempWordHolder.Append(" ");
    tempWordHolder.AppendLine(word);

    counter++;
    if (counter < 500)
        continue;

    counter = 0;
    words.Add(tempWordHolder.ToString());
    tempWordHolder.Clear();
}

if (tempWordHolder.Length > 0)
{
    words.Add(tempWordHolder.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I disadvice the use of `string tempWordHolder` for performance reasons. Use `StringBuilder` instead. You create thousands of `string`s in no time.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I edited my code. But i'm not sure if i used the StringBuilder in the right way.

Comment: I edited your code a little. Feel free to rollback if you feel it isn't useful.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickHofman that was constructive. I just changed  (counter < 500) as I think its the right way. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are interested in words. the whole text can be split by Space or newline. split itself will give you an array of words. And based on your requirement start taking the required no of words by the index. And start pushing to your new sub arrays.please Let me know if code sample is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Hurray! I found it myself!

Thanks again!!! :))

```
 $string = "1 2 3 4 5";
 $ex = explode(' ',$string);   

 foreach ($ex as $row) {
   echo $row . "<br>\r\n";
 }
```